# Reusing writable objects in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to find the performance benefits of reusing writables vs creating new objects in the wordcount mapreduce program. However the two versions take almost the same time to complete however large the input data is.

I also tried giving the task a lower heap space by changing,

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx120m</value>
</property>
```

But both the versions ran a little slower when compared to a higher heap space. I was never able to get the program which reuses writables to perform better. Am I missing something here ?

The portion of wordcount that I had modified,

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    context.write(new Text(itr.nextToken()), new IntWritable(1));
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'reusing writables'?

Comment: @ryanbwork it is common practice to take that `new IntWritable(1)` and make it a static variable and reuse the same one over and over. Same with the `Text` object-- it's common practice to reuse the same object, but change the contents with `.set`.

Comment: 'Almost the same time' can you elaborate? task time reducing from 50 seconds to 45 seconds on average may not seem that big a deal, but a job running 1000's of tasks, or a heavily loaded cluster this could add up some hours of runtime saved.

Comment: The difference in the running time of the jobs varies from 3 to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a big deal for two reasons:

1. You do `IO` which is **slow**, so it won't be a big deal to create a few new objects per input line and let it be garbage collected.
2. Most probably, you have a very low memory footprint anyway. So if you create objects, they will be stored in heap memory as long as a certain memory threshold will be exceeded. So it is likely that your other solution takes more heap memory than the other. If you now lower your heap memory, the `Garbage Collector` must run more often, because the threshold exceeds more often. You would see this in the GC logs if you turn that on.

Another reason might be the way you are measuring the time, a `Map task` involves a lot of RPC communication in the back, so you can't always be 100% sure that your data isn't skewed by network congestion or other environmental effects.

Comment: Thanks for that. I turned on the GC logs, increased the memory to 2GB and noticed that one version uses about 5 times more heap space than the other. I have read that reusing writables causes improvements with respect to running time and I am unable to observe it.

Comment: @Chitra how much data are you inputting?

Comment: I tried with a 5MB file and a 5GB file and with both the versions the running times differed by 3 to 10 seconds.

Comment: @Chitra That is interesting, maybe runtime optimizations by the JVM are going to omit the object creation. The `context.write` is directly serializing it to a byte buffer, so the instance is never used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is which is the performance bottle neck here, or which impact performance more, reusable IntVariable or the IO.

Reuse variable is theoretically better, but based on Amdahl's law http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law, the improvement may be even not noticeable.